# how to duplicate all the databases with limited rows in the tables

Tags: mysql

How can I duplicate my databases with limited number of rows in the tables.

Basically the duplicated db must have the same properties of original database but limited rows in the tables.

Comment: Limited as in number of rows per table?

Comment: yes. original table may have millions of rows but the duplicated can have say 1000 and should have same properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, first create a similar table using

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_name_duplicate LIKE tlb_name;
```

then insert limited number of records into it using

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name_duplicate(SELECT * FROM tlb_name LIMIT 10);
```

to insert 10 records

Comment: but u have to do that individually for each table in the database. I wanted to automate and write a script so that even in the future if any new tables are added, the script takes care of it.

Comment: isnt there any query like dump to do that at the db level rather than table level

Comment: yes. basically cloning the database but with limited rows in each table

Comment: well den u better write stored procedure and call those 2 functions in dat procedure and u can pass table name as parameters.Loop through all tables in the database and call procedure for each table.U can get name of all tables using Show Tables

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, is to use the `--where` option in the `mysqldump`, so you could create something similar to a SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id > (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_name) - 10
```

re-written for the `mysqldump` (but you'll have to dump each table at a time, not the whole database):

```
mysqldump [options] --where="id > (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_name) - 10" | mysql --host=host --user=user --password=password some_database
```

More information at [MySQL Reference Guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where).